# meteor .helpers function input parameter to return an object

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, parameter-passing, aggregation-framework

I am still trying to learn meteor, and would like to return the average score of a person (based on their numerous ratings) -- a user will be rated on 4 variables, And i would like to return their "scorecard" using a helper function.

What is the best (most efficient) way to list all users in a database (based on a certain filter) -- using a helper function?

my Collection (workers):

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d3dc44353972841db96049"),
    "name" : "James",
    "surname" : "Jones",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-03-23T14:31:32.512Z")
    ],
    "Hist" : [ 
        {
            "itemDate" : "01/2017",
            "skill" : "",
            "review" : {
                "client" : "101"
            },
            "traits" : {
                "speed" : 3.0,
                "distance" : 2.0,
                "reliability" : 3.0,
                "overall" : 4.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

my Template:

```
<template name="scoreCard" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <div class="col s3">Average Speed</div>
                <div class="progress grey lighten-4">
                    <div class="determinate" style="width:{{aSpeed this.userId }}%">
                        <span class="amount">{{aSpeed this.userId}}</span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

my Helper:

```
Template.scoreCard.helpers({
    userSkills(userId){
        return Workers.aggregate(
        {$unwind:"$Hist"},
        {$group: {
               _id:ObjectId(userId),
                aSpeed: { $avg: "$Hist.traits.speed"},
                aDist: { $avg: "$Hist.traits.distance"},
                aRel: { $avg: "$Hist.traits.reliability"},
                aOver: { $avg: "$Hist.traits.overall"}
            }
        })
            },
        });
```

as you can see above... i am not correctly passing the userID to return the actual defined average per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the actual `ObjectId` value for the group key, use the document's `_id` key name and create an initial **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline that will filter the documents for that particular parameterised id i.e.

```
Template.scoreCard.helpers({
    userSkills(userId) {
        return Workers.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId(userId) } },
            { "$unwind": "$Hist" },
            { "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id", // or _id: null
                "aSpeed": { "$avg": "$Hist.traits.speed" },
                "aDist": { "$avg": "$Hist.traits.distance" },
                "aRel": { "$avg": "$Hist.traits.reliability" },
                "aOver": { "$avg": "$Hist.traits.overall" }
            } }
        ]);
    }
});
```

---

If you can run MongoDB 3.4 and greater which has very useful new aggregation features, you can try out the **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** operator which allows you to calculate the average from a list without the need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**, you can just do it in a single pipeline as follows:

```
Template.scoreCard.helpers({

    sum(key) {
        return {
            "$reduce": {
                "input": "$Hist",
                "initialValue": 0,
                "in": { "$add": ["$$value", key] }
            }
        }
    }

    userSkills(userId) {
        return Workers.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId(userId) } },
            { "$addFields": { 
                "histSize": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ { "$size": "$Hist" }, 0 ] },
                        1,
                        { "$size": "$Hist" } 
                    ]
                }
            } },
            { "$addFields": {
                "aSpeed": { "$divide": [sum("$$this.traits.speed"), "$histSize"] },
                "aDist": { "$divide": [sum("$$this.traits.distance"), "$histSize"] },
                "aRel": { "$divide": [sum("$$this.traits.reliability"), "$histSize"] },
                "aOver": { "$divide": [sum("$$this.traits.overall", "$histSize"] }
            } }
        ]);
    }
});
```